# SetTexture and Sprites not working as intended! (LibGDX)

Tags: android, libgdx, textures, sprite

I searched for and wide on the internet and I have yet to find an answer. I have an object called GameIcon which extends Sprite. Everything about it is okay except for the texture. Here is my code for the GameIcon class.

```
package com.xx4everPixelatedxx.gaterunner.sprites;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.xx4everPixelatedxx.gaterunner.GateRunner;

import javax.xml.soap.Text;

/**
 * Created by Michael Jan on 8/17/2015.
 */
public class GameIcon extends Sprite {
    private int vX = 3;
    private int vY = 3;
    private int r = 9;
    private int rotation;

    private Vector3 position;

    private Texture texture;

    public GameIcon(int x, int y) {
        position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("icon_players/icon1.png"));
        setTexture(texture);
    }

    public void update() {
        position.add(vX, vY, 0);
        rotation = rotation + r;

        rotation = rotation % 360;

        setRotation(rotation);
        setOriginCenter();
    }

    public void addPosition(int x, int y) {
        position.add(x, y, 0);
        setOriginCenter();
    }

    public void negateVelocityX() {
        vX = -vX;
    }

    public void negateRotation() {
        r = -r;
    }

    public Vector3 getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public int getvY() {
        return vY;
    }

    public void setvY(int vY) {
        this.vY = vY;
    }

    public int getvX() {
        return vX;
    }

    public void setvX(int vX) {
        this.vX = vX;
    }
}
```

Here is the icon1.png:
https://i.gyazo.com/1d52f5e58b227f08809f6c14ae4c94a4.png

Here is what I am getting:
https://i.gyazo.com/1881a9392955af34de5c55b9b8fac391.png

Note that the rotation of the image and the particles are intended. The problem is that the big square should be the texture (icon1.png), and I do not know how to fix this.

(Not enough reputation to post pictures)

Comment: How do you render it?

Comment: You probably should not be hiding the super class's references to `position`, `texture`, and `rotation`. This is a bug waiting to happen. And there's no reason to subclass Sprite if you are hiding all its functionality.

Comment: @m.antkowicz name.render(batch);

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm still in the process of extending Sprite. Before, sprite was just a field, and I had to call getSprite all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with LibGDX, but this may have something to do with the fact that you are *maybe* overwriting `TextureRegion.texture`. Could you try to user your parent class [Sprite(Texture)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#Sprite-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture-) constructor like this:

```
...
public class GameIcon extends Sprite {
   private int vX = 3;
   private int vY = 3;
   private int r = 9;
   private int rotation;

   private Vector3 position;

   //private Texture texture; 

   public GameIcon(int x, int y) {
       super(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("icon_players/icon1.png")))
       position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
   }
...
```

As stated by Tenfour04 in comments, this method works because the parent's constructor applies the width and height of the texture, while `setTexture()` does not.

Comment: You may not be familiar with it, but your answer is spot on.

Comment: The reason this is necessary is that the `setTexture` method does not apply the width and height of the texture, but the super constructor does.

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04. Do you mind if I update the answer with your explanation?